# Reading Tar Files In Matlab

Tags: matlab, gzip, gis, tar, shapefile

I have a link: https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/has/HAS011460917/

There are a list of tar files.

In the tar files, there should be hourly precipitation amounts and they should be designated by location (longitude or latitude or pixels).
I am told that it is possible for Matlab to import this data and organize (tabulate or analyze) the precipitation amounts according to location for each file.

I started with

`filenames = untar('C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\NWS_NEXRAD_NXL2SR_KOKX_20100203140000_20100203145959.tar')`

Then a few gz files would appear in the Current Folder window.
I would then write something like

`files = gunzip('KOKX20100203_145516_V03.gz')`

This will produce a file with a name `KOKX20100203_145516_V03`

When I click table, it shows up in unicode.
So currently, I am even unable to get a legible table, let alone tabulate results according to location.

If anyone is able to help in any way, at any level (not necessarily even organizing by location, but just even reading or opening), that would be great.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Those data files you get when you gunzip the `.gz` files are binary files of some sort. You'll need to find some documentation for their file format to figure out how to read them in. Is there documentation on that NOAA web site? Could whoever pointed you at these files tell you how they're encoded?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded NOAA'S Weather and Climate Toolkit https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/install.php Now, I am able to export the files shp and read them. Thanks